# Trying to Publish an InfoPath 2013 form on a SharePoint 2013 Site

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, forms-services, infopath-data-connections

I have created a smart form in InfoPath (using the SharePoint List template I believe) that I would like to publish to SharePoint site but am getting several errors. First, I have one error occurring in three places which states "Choice section cannot store bound data type." The second error, which appears when I try to publish the form, is "InfoPath failed to publish because the default content type in the library is not based on the Form content type."

Has anyone experienced either of these problems with InfoPath and SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I faced the same issue, actually my InfoPath form was targeted to publish into Document Library instead if Form Library.

In your case i guess you are also doing the same mistake. You may have your published target wrongly specified.

Comment: yes it works for me